# ColdFusion 2016 has modified the usage of CFloop tag returned by Code Analyzer

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016, cfloop

I tried to run the ColdFusion Code Analyzer over my entire project to check if there are some issues reported and for every single CFLOOP used with queries I got this warning:

> ColdFusion 2016 has modified the usage of CFloop tag. How to fix:
>   Check the usage of the tag CFloop.

I repeat, I got this warning for all instanced of CFLOOP in my files and they look like:

```
<cfloop query="getSampleItems">
```

I have no errors in my code, everything works fine. I wonder why CF is saying I am not using correctly CFLOOP tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting this as Severity - *Info* or *Error*? I think these are just information provided so that users migrating from old versions of CF does not run into errors.

Comment: You can make use "Filter by severity" in Advanced settings to filter these out. Or filter by Tags provided in Advanced settings.

Comment: I am getting this as Info. But I don't know what is deprecated to this? I couldn't find any changes to CFLOOP used for a query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, nothing is wrong

Long answer: `<cfloop>` changed for arrays and lists. It is possible that if you were using `<cfloop>` in an array or list, you would have to change things. There is also a possiblity that you may want to run through your query as an array instead of a query.

I suspect that none of these apply to your code, hence consider this to be a false positive.

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop-looping-over-a-list-a-file-or-an-array.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know they added extra functions for looping through arrays, lists, collections. But I am using CFLOOP with a query... Nothing changed there...

Comment: I should have said: Short answer, nothing is wrong with your code